# Jquery validation of a text box not printing message more than once

Tags: jquery

Below code is validating properly.When i first submit the form,it shows the error message,second time when i submit,it is validating but not showing the error message.

```
function validate()
{
 var textbox= $("#inputtextbox").val();
 var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})$/;
 if(!match.test(textbox)) {
 $("#dataError").text('Maximum 3 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
return false;
```

**update**

```
var textbox= $("#inputtextbox").val();
     var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})$/;
     if(!match.test(textbox)) {
     $("#dataError").text('Maximum 3 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.').fadeOut(5000);
    return false;
```

}

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" >
      <span id=""></span>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fadeOut() when validation fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function validate()
{
 var textbox= $("#inputtextbox").val();
 var match = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,})$/;
 if(!match.test(textbox)) {
 $("#dataError").text('Maximum 3 alpha numeric characters and space allowed.');
 $("#dataError").show().fadeOut(5000);

return false;
}
<span id=""></span>

<form onsubmit="return validate()" >
```

Comment: :I posted update,if i copy the same code for another text box,it is not showing error message,if the 1st textbox is correct then it is showing second text box.